# Using shared pointers in map

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm trying to decide what is best choice to use in my HW.
I have a map (I coded it) that supposed to store integer id's as keys and shared pointer of class named fan as values:

```
Map<Id, shared_ptr<Fan>> Online_list;
```

what is better to use `shared_ptr<Fan>&` or none reference ?

My homework is about creating server like Facebook with fans to be on-line and offline,so im having two maps one called `Online_list` and other is `Offline_list`, so when fan is disconnected i need to remove him from on-line list and add him to offline list.

Comment: If you store an actual reference type, then you have to manage the lifetime of that object elsewhere.  That's just more work than necessary.

Comment: I don't see how this is answerable without knowing what you're attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` is a sort of reference. A pointer with memory management. You can store the plain `shared_ptr` since the internal refers to the same data anyway(Copy constructor increment reference count, etc).

Answer (score 1):

*Usually* it's best to not store a pointer *at all*, but just store the `Fan` object by-value.  Does it really make sense for `two` things to own this `Fan` object?

However, assuming that your design is correct, then you should simply store the `shared_ptr` by-value.

Comment: use it makes sense , because i have other maps to contain same fans.

Comment: @Emad4U:  And why does *that* make sense?

Comment: because that what im requested to do.